# Won't load label text at start of windows form

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that just displays the Code of the day at my school. but there is a problem with the way the label I'm using loads. The label starts off displaying "label1" and only changes to the Code of the day when I click on it. Can anyone figure out what is wrong. here is a snippet of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string GetCOTD()
        {
            //a function for getting the the COTD
            string sourceString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://guestwifi.discoveryschool.org.uk/cotd/?id=01234");
            sourceString = sourceString.Substring(959, 8);
            return sourceString;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = GetCOTD();
        }
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = GetCOTD();
        }

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = GetCOTD();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try put label1.Text = GetCOTD(); after InitializeComponent(); and run?

Comment: You have double clicked in the GUI designer on the label (twice) - that is the reason why the useless event handler methods (label1_Click) were created. Those are only executed when you click the label

Comment: Now I have and it works, thank you so much. :-) @Chase

Comment: Try to figure out how to solve problem by yourself, use google and other sources before posting it here. You just need to assign some value to .Text property of your label as Chase said....

Comment: @Fabjan no need to be horrible.

Comment: @JordanYoung, good, I will add as answer.

Comment: @JordanYoung i am not 'horrible' . Just wanted to say that questions like this was already answered zillion times... So you could at least google it  before asking zillion +1 time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have the `Form1_Load` handler mapped (i.e. it's just a function, in C# it's not enough to just declare it, you should also bind it to the event). Check in the form events (Properties window, Events tab), if you have `Load` event actually associated with `Form1_Load`.

Comment: Given the OP's problems with event hooking, this seems to be the correct answer!

Comment: damn this was a long time ago but I've learned a lot about c# since then and yes this was actually the better answer, the other answer was a neat bodge that got it working but this is the better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put `label1.Text = GetCOTD();` after `InitializeComponent();` , it should help.

Comment: I had to wait as it wouldn't let me click the tick. very sorry.

Comment: If it helped, it was only by chance.